# Why does the new built image does not have the new installed package?

Tags: docker

**TL;DR: once the image built it needs to be start as a new container. Old base-container is not updated through the build process.**

I have built an image from Dockerfile starting from ubuntu, I've noticed that although I am installing php5-pgsql on the Dockerfile:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

After building the image successfully, I've noticed it would not have any effect on the container.

I had to exec into the container, and run the above command lines, then restart the container before I can start using the installed extension.

Any one can explain why? isn't the image has the extension already installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image itself it is just a template used to run containers. You have to start a new container based on the newly generated image(i.e. template).

Comment: Thanks, but I found that the newly built image has a none name, while I am referencing the old image!

Comment: You can specify the Image name/tag in docker build command using -t option

Comment: Does it work now? You can also use `docker commit <container_ID> <new_image_name>` to create a new image from the docker container you are executing the commands into.